# Accessing FTP server with Python fails with "getaddrinfo" error

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to access the open DLP Test FTP server as a practice. I keep getting a *getaddrinfo* error but I am unsure of where I'm going wrong. I am using Python 2 on a Windows 10, and have already checked that I am not behind a proxy.

Code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('ftp://ftp.dlptest.com/')
...
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 135, in connect
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ftp = FTP('ftp.dlptest.com')
```

instead.

The first argument of [`FTP` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP) is `host` – a *hostname* or an *IP address* – not a *URL*.